# Chrome applies height property of media query only on refresh

Tags: css, google-chrome, height, media-queries, refresh

I have a header with varying height by media queries. When I resize window on FF or even IE, it applies new height value immediately. The problem is, that Chrome only does it on browser refresh. It applies any other value immediately (like background-color), but not the height. Also this doesn't happen on page zoom, only on window resize.

```
@media all and (max-width: 30em) {
header { height: 40%; background-color: #333333; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 56em) {
header { height: 50%; background-color: #666666; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 56em) {
header { height: 60%; background-color: #cccccc; }
}
```

Here is the Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPmrNW

Is this Chrome bug or there's something wrong with the code?

Comment: Seems to work in Codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, this problem is only encountered on chrome when you resize the window, it is most likely a problem with Chrome rather than your code.

Comment: Thank you, it was a minor Chrome update that actually solved this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in codepen with the latest version of chrome.
Check your Chrome version, your code works.